# Mostrar icono en vez de numero

Tags: javascript, angular

Hola estoy realizando una app en angular y quisiera saber como puedo mostrar un icono en vez de un numero, me explico:

Yo ingreso un formulario y selecciono una calificación, el servidor me devuelve toda la respuesta del formulario incluyendo la calificación, que puede ser de 1-5 necesito que en el front esa respuesta me la muestre como iconos, si es 1 = un icono  2 = dos iconos y así sucesivamente.

Comment: Agrega lo que has intentado, porque ayudarte bajo suposiciones es imposible. ¿Qué devuelve el servidor? ¿En qué formato? ¿Cómo lo vas a mostrar en el front? Te invito a repasar [ask] y a leer [mcve]. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Crea un switch y pone los casos de 1 a 5
en cada caso pone el icono que quieras e insterta ese elemento en el html con backtiks

Vamos a suponer que vos necesitas visuar los iconos en un div que accedes con viewchild que se llama contenedor. Luego crea con los backtiks el elemento a insertar con la clase o lo que fuese que cree el icono

```
@ViewChild('contenedor',{static: true})
contenedor: ElementRef

const crearElemento = codigoIcono=> {
 let elemento = ` 
            <i>
                ${codigoIcono}
            </i>` 
return elemento
}
```

Ahora lo que tenes que hacer es en cada caso del switch insertar el elemento en el contenedor pasandole el codigo por ejemplo:

```
switch (expresion) {
case 1:
    this.contenedor.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', crearElemento('trash'))    
    break;
case 2:
    // repetir con otro codigo
default:
    break;
}
```